# android custom DatePicker - "OK" button

Tags: android, datepicker, android-alertdialog

I wanted to implement a material design DatePicker in which user could select a date range. So I found this wonderful library on github that does exactly what I want: 
https://github.com/vikramkakkar/SublimePicker

But there is absolutely no documentation on how to use it. After researching for hours, I figured out how to get the calendar to display. Below is my code. The problem is, I don't know how to `setPositiveButton` or `setNegativeButton`. Without that, I can't save the date/date range.

```
SublimePickerFragment.Callback mFragmentCallback = null;
SublimePickerFragment pickerFrag = new SublimePickerFragment();
pickerFrag.setCallback(mFragmentCallback);

SublimeOptions sublimeOptions = new SublimeOptions();
sublimeOptions.setDisplayOptions(SublimeOptions.ACTIVATE_DATE_PICKER);
sublimeOptions.setPickerToShow(SublimeOptions.Picker.DATE_PICKER);
sublimeOptions.setDateParams(Calendar.getInstance());
sublimeOptions.setCanPickDateRange(true);
sublimeOptions.setAnimateLayoutChanges(true);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("SUBLIME_OPTIONS", sublimeOptions);

pickerFrag.setArguments(bundle);
pickerFrag.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);
pickerFrag.show(this.getFragmentManager(), "SUBLIME_PICKER");
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: your question is about this library ? or Android date picker, you want to add ok cancel buttons ?

Comment: It's about the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution. I had to setup a call back function that would get called when OK or CANCEL was clicked. Below is the code. Hope this helps someone!

```
SublimePickerFragment.Callback mFragmentCallback = new SublimePickerFragment.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onCancelled() { 
        // when CANCEL is clicked
    }
    @Override
    public void onDateTimeRecurrenceSet(SelectedDate selectedDate, int hourOfDay, int minute, SublimeRecurrencePicker.RecurrenceOption recurrenceOption, String recurrenceRule) {
        // when OK is clicked
        System.out.println(selectedDate.toString());
    }
};
```